# Krita - Drawing a gradient along a path

Tags: path, gradient, krita, bezier-curve

How would you draw a curve/path and make a gradient face the direction of the path? Let me show you what I mean: https://prnt.sc/1036pgl

If that isn't clear, I want that path to have a gradient moving dynamically along each of those directions along the path. It would look like a cleaner, procedural version of this: https://prnt.sc/1036suz

I realize this is probably a longshot, but if anybody would know how to do this it's you guys.

Comment: It depends on how precise you need it to be, but I think I would use a selection (as the perimeter) and a soft round brush (airbrush) along the edge of the selection to create the gradient: https://youtu.be/Hrxn5pEc2zM It really helps to have really low opacity so you can do multiple passes. The bigger the gradient, the easier it is to brush in because you don't need to hit the edge fo the selection as accurately. I wouldn't recommend brushing it with a mouse like I did in the video. It's really difficult to catch them...